# ASP.NET Windows Console Files + filename to ZIP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to zip files from folder X to folder Y. When the files from folder X are zipped into folder Y. The files in folder X needs to be removed. The zip name must be the name of the file with the .DBS in that folder.

So I need to read whats the file name of the .DBS file is. Then I need to zip all the files in folder X to folder Y with the name: "Filename" (this is the same as the .DBS file) If the files are zipped and well in folder Y they need to be removed from folder X.

The code that I got at the moment will move the files of folder X too Y. So this is a start. My question is how can I get the name of the file too be the zip folder name.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace Ramasoftzipper
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string fileName = @"160001.DBS";
        string sourcePath = @"C:\RMExport";
        string targetPath = @"C:\Exportrm";
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        string startPath = @"C:\RMExport";
        string zipPath = (fileName);
        string extractPath = @"C:\Exportrm";


        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }


        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);


        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);


            foreach (string s in files)
            {

                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");



        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.DBS");` this will retrieve all the filenames that have a .DBS extension. Is that what you need ?

Comment: @bkaf yes thats what I need but my zip code still isnt working. Do you know what I should do to fix that?

Comment: @bkaf where should I place: string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.DBS"); In my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(only explaining this much because I know you and you need to learn this stuff, yo :P)

you could try something like this, read comments in code for more info, this code is only showing you how to zip all files in a folder, try the next step of adding certain extentions yourself

```
//files to zip, you can also use the same method as above to let the user determine what path to zip
string path = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Pictures";            
string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\result.zip";            

//zip files
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, zipPath);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

//some debugging
foreach (string filePath in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filePath);
}
//wait untill user presses enter
Console.ReadLine();
```

**[EDIT]**

setting the name of the zip file to a file name:

replace

```
string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\result.zip";
```

with

```
//get all files from directory decladed by path
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
//select the 1st one and delete the folder information so just the file name is left with it's extention
string zipName = files[0].Replace(path, "");

//delete the extention
int index = zipName.IndexOf(".");
if (index > 0)
     zipName = zipName.Substring(0, index);

//assemble the zip location with the generated file name         
string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\"+ zipName + ".zip";
```

and delete

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

under

```
//zip files
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, zipPath);
```

Comment: Hey Luuk, How can I give the zip file the name from my .dbs file

Comment: is there anyway how I can delete the files from the ramasoft folder if they are zipped?

Comment: string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path); gives an error. files is already defined in this scope

Comment: if it's already defined, delete it, rename it if you're using another path but still be able to use the other one, or remove `string[]` infront of `files` on the line where the error occurs

Comment: And could u explain your code a bit so I can learn from this? especially : string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
string zipName = files[0].Replace(path, "");

int index = zipName.IndexOf(".");
if (index > 0)
     zipName = zipName.Substring(0, index);

 string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\"+ zipName + ".zip";

Comment: added some explenation, I hope you understand it now

Comment: Luuk? how can I add the letters RM in front of my zip name?

Comment: `string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\RM"+ zipName + ".zip";` come on bruh, you can think logical enough to know this :P

Comment: it doesnt work. I just need too get the zip name from hello.zip too RMhello.zip

Comment: oh sorry, my fault, you should do `string zipPath = @"C:\Users\WsLocal.NL-ROE2-W297\Desktop\zip\RM"+ zipName.Replace(@"\", "") + ".zip"; `